# How to redirect to another page in magento

Tags: html, magento, backend

I am using the magento platform and I want to redirect users to another page on my website but I don't know how to do this. I have 3 options Title page, URL Key and State. I have a title in the URL Key I put the page that I want to be redirected and on the State it is by default Activated but I have the following error There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.

Do I have to put something else in the URL Key?

Comment: From where you are try to redirect your page??

Comment: From a page where I have no data to another page where I have categories. If this is the link to my other page http://www.mywebsite.com/lights.html  all I have to do is to copy the word lights and put it in the URL Key box right?

Answer (score 1):

Magneto has the URL redirects built in.

Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

From there you can make a rewrite to forward from xxx to xxx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the URL key of a CMS page to `something`you can just go ahead and edit the link to `/something` and it will redirect you to the correct page.

Comment: You mean that in the content box I should put /something?

Comment: you need to describe what kind of redirection you want to use. just a default link on a certain site?

Comment: A default link. I want that when I press the respective button instead of showing blak to redirect me to another page of my website (to go to /something)

Comment: yes, just poot `/something` into the link and make sure you have created a CMS packe with the same URL key

Comment: I did this and now it shows me this error There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.

Comment: so you haven't set the url key in the CMS page right